# Parse specific text file into data

Tags: python, parsing

i have a text file with data looking like this:

```
[not important metadata...] 
{
  ["Servers"] = {
    ["4441_Auberdine"] = {                    <- Important data
      ["Alliance"] =                          <- Important data
        ["Nain"] = {                          <- Important data
          ["Paladin"] = {                     <- Important data
            ["Dalkahm"] = {                   <- Important data
              80, -- [1]                      <- Important data
              "One For Hole", -- [2]          <- Important data
              "2023-07-30", -- [3]            <- Not important data 
              1669938317, -- [4]              <- Not important data
              2, -- [5]                       <- Not important data
            },
...
```

I'm trying to parse that file and store the data in this structure:

```
id_1 {
Player_name : "Dalkahm"
Server      : "4441_Auberdine"
Faction     : "Alliance"
Race        : "Nain"
Class       : "Paladin"
Level       : 80
Guild       : "One For Hole"
},
```

Do you have any idea how to that? I have knowledge in C programming but nothing in python :s

I'm new to Python, so i thought about using my knowledge in C and parse it the hard way (using while and some regex) but i would like to know if it exist easiers methods to do that.

Comment: [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) is a list of parsing libraries for Python. Take your pick.

Comment: Honestly this looks like a Lua table to me.
Maybe there's a library to parse a lua table.